# How to get execution millisecond time of a command in zsh?

Tags: zsh, time

The `time` only print the the execution second time of a command.

If there is a solution like IPython's powerful `timeit` magic command, great.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

zsh's `time` uses the `TIMEFMT` variable to control the format. [By default](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html), this is `%J %U user %S system %P cpu %*E total`, which produces the following.

```
$ time sleep 2
sleep 2 0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.002 total
```

This *does* produce millisecond accuracy (at least for `total`), so perhaps your system has a different default set (lagging distro?), or has modified `TIMEFMT`.

Have a look at the [manual page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html) for possible formats. I use the following in `~/.zshrc`:

```
TIMEFMT=$'\n================\nCPU\t%P\nuser\t%*U\nsystem\t%*S\ntotal\t%*E'
```

which produces the following.

```
$ time sleep 2 

================
CPU     0%
user    0.003
system  0.000
total   2.006
```

Answer (score 2):

The ipython `timeit` magic command will by default print a statistics report over several executions of your statement. The zsh reserved word `time` will only run your command once.

When you only care about measuring the execution time of external commands (and not builtins and functions) you can use [hyperfine](https://github.com/sharkdp/hyperfine).  It's a program that repeatedly executes a command for you and prints some statistics.